# css layered positioning

Tags: html, css-position, css

Is it possible to position a div as a layer on top of the webpage html but:

1. be fixed (same position if I scroll the page)
2. have the features of absolute positioning, eg. does not disturb the html layout

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have you tried:

```
position: fixed;
top: 12px;
left: 34px;
z-index: 54;
```

?

The element will be fixed (also during scroll) on the top of the page, and you can place it giving x/y coordinates just as you do with `position: absolute` elements...

Comment: `position: fixed` is disturbing the html layout, I need it to flow above it

Comment: It should not disturb your layout. In fact, this should make your element floating above the page! What do you mean? Can you provide a jsFiddle example?

Comment: It does work in jsFiddle so I guess it's some css conflict on the live site, thanks.

Answer (score 3):

[position:fixed;](http://css-tricks.com/absolute-relative-fixed-positioining-how-do-they-differ/) is your answer.

Comment: As you mentioned it should be 'fixed' so its only way to fix. Please post your code so that we can know what it needs changes.